# Is there a simple system that has $\text{SU}(3)$ symmetry?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, intuition, symmetry

The buckle at the end of a belt has $\text{SU}(2)$ symmetry, if the rotations around the three coordinate axes are taken as generators.  See, for example,  the paper by Hart, Francis and Kauffman, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2389584_Visualizing_Quaternion_Rotation . You can also use the hand at the end of your arm to visualize SU(2), including its double cover of SO(3).

Is there something similar for $\text{SU}(3)$ symmetry? Is there a simple system, maybe from everyday life, that realizes this symmetry?

Alternatively: how do you picture $\text{SU}(3)$ in your head?

Comment: Regarding how to picture $SU(3)$, I guess since $SU(3)/SU(2) \simeq S^5$ one could "picture" $SU(3)$ as a 5-sphere's worth of $SU(2)$s (the non-trivial one, as $\pi_4(S^3) = Z/2$).

Comment: Quantum chromodynamics is somehow related to SU(3), I believe

Answer (score 10):

Outside of quantum physics, both SU(2) and SU(3) appear in the context of polarization optics. For a plane wave the rotation of the two components of the polarization (perpendicular to the propagation direction) are represented by an element of SU(2). To describe the more general case of an arbitrary wave field (without a fixed propagation direction), three components need to be rotated and SU(3) is needed. See, for example, [SU(3) representation for the polarisation of light](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225778441_SU3_representation_for_the_polarisation_of_light) (1980) and [Parameters characterizing electromagnetic wave polarization](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/183b/183ed5d44c429991c4785fb3fbba712c7b39.pdf?_ga=2.266326346.473049871.1509401539-1721347627.1458159192) (2000).

Comment: Could you recommend a text to read in more detail about rotations of an internal degree of freedom from a mathematical point of view?

Comment: The belt trick (or plate trick) that Francesco refers to is a trick to visualize SU(2), not just SO(3), so goes beyond the local isomorphism of those groups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_trick. It is hard to state precisely how the trick enables us  to visualize SU(2), but that is certainly the purpose of the trick.

Comment: Carlo, I added a reference to Francesco's question.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: Feynman Lectures on Physics, vol. 3, has a whole chapter titled "Spin 1 particles".

Comment: somehow I interpreted the "every day life" part of the OP that this should be an application of SU(3) to a _classical,_ as opposed to quantum system; but indeed, in the quantum context SU(2s+1) appears for any spin-s particle. In the classical context I only know of the application to light polarisation.

Comment: @BenMcKay My understanding is that the belt trick (somehow) demonstrates a loop in SO(3) that is not homotopic to the trivial loop, while twice this loop is homotopic to the trivial loop. This just shows that SO(3) has an element of order 2 in its fundamental group, but I don't know how it can be used to show that the fundamental group is of order 2 or that the universal cover is SU(2).

Comment: I assume the belt trick is isomorphic to the arm trick. With a little hand- (arm?) waving, you can argue that your arm represents a path in SO(3) from the rotation given by your hand to a basepoint (your fixed shoulder), so, in that sense, it's an element in the universal cover.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Sorry, I understood (to an extent) what's in Feynman but failed to relate it to what I don't understand here. I understand perfectly what is rotation of an object in space. I can imagine the reason why this is called external rotation and that there might be some opposite thing called internal rotation - something like a gadget with a gyroscope hidden deeply inside. What I don't understand is how to describe this purely mathematically. For external rotations we have a body in R$^3$ and an action of a rotation group on R$^3$. What must we have to describe internal rotations?

Comment: Internal rotation are not rotation. they corresponds to transformation of the state of a system that have nothing to do with space. For exemple, if a particul has non zero Spin, then it has different possible spin state (like "up and down") and it has a group of "rotation" SU(n) that acts on (superposition of) those spin state which might have nothing to do with a rotation in space. It is a bit confusing for spin because we think of it as small arrows that have something to do with space, but you can think about other quantum properties like the "color" of a Quark and its SU(3) action.

Comment: მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: In "daily life" (=classical mechanics) we only need SO(3) (and SU(2) is only used sometimes as a technical device to simplify SO(3)). In quantum mechanics, the phase space must be a complex space. The quantity we are talking about is spin, which is also called "internal rotation" to distinguish it from "external rotation" of a rigid body. For spin 1/2 SU(2) is used (because the spin takes 2 values $\pm1/2$ so we need a 2-dimensional complex space). For spin 1 there are three values 0,1,-1, so we need a three dimensional complex space on which SU(3) acts.

Comment: @SimonHenry Thank you! I suppose I specifically had in mind spin - mathematical formalism for its description. You see, from the mathematical point of view there are indeed representations of, say SO(3) which look like having nothing to do with the standard representation on $\mathbb R^3$ - but after all there are not that many irreducible finite dimensional representations, and I believe they still can be constructed in one way or other either from the standard one, or from the standard representation of its universal covering SU(2) on $\mathbb C^2$, no?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thank you for further clarifications! So is it correct to say that possible states of the spin of a photon "live" on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ (quotient of $\mathbb C^3$ by phases) and that observables relevant to this state space are operators that act on it through the standard representation of SU(3)? Sorry for more questions, but...

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: Sorry, photon is a bad example here. It is only for a massive spin 1 particle the spin state is $C^3$. So Feynman;s chapter we were discussing is about massive particle, not photon.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko OK. Also, actually the quotient is not so relevant, since eigenvalues carry essential information anyway.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: Yes, physicists usually work with a vector space rather than the quotient.

Answer (score 9):

One of the simplest mechanical systems having an SU(3) dynamical symmetry is the three dimensional isotropic harmonic oscillator. Its phase space is $\mathbb{R}^6$ parametrized by 3 position coordinates $x_i$ and 3 momenta $p_i$, $i=1,2,3$. 
A fixed energy hypersurface in phase space is given by the constraint (in units where the natural frequency is 1):
$$\sum_i x_i^2 + \sum_i p_i^2  = E $$
This a the $5$-dimensional sphere $S^5$, and the set of classical trajectories (the reduced phase space corresponding to the Hamiltonian action) on this hypersurface is the complex projective space $CP^2$ , obtained from $S^5$ by a Hopf fibration and from the original phase space by Marsden-Weinstein symplectic reduction with respect to the action of the total energy function:
$$CP^2 = S^5/U(1) = \mathbb{C}^3//U(1)$$
Being a $SU(3)$  homogeneous space $CP^2$ has a natural $SU(3)$action: 
The functions representing $SU(3)$ in the $CP^2$ Poisson algebra have simple geometric expressions:

1. First we have the three angular momentum components:
   $$L_{ij} = x_ip_j-x_jp_i$$
2. In addition we have 5 quadrupole moments built from the (traceless)symmetric combinations of the coordinates and momenta:
   $$Q_{ij} = \frac{3}{2} (x_ip_j+x_jp_i) - \delta_{ij} \sum_k x_kp_k$$
   Together they generate the $SU(3)$ Lie algebra. The quadrupole moment space is closed under the $SU(2)$ action generated by the angular momenta. They transform according to the spin-2 representation.

Physically, the quadrupole moments interact with gradients of an external magnetic field. If the harmonic oscillator is charged, then its interaction energy with an external magnetic field has the form:
$$E_{int} = \sum_{ijk} \epsilon_{ijk}L_{ij}B_k+ \sum_{ij} Q_{ij} \partial_{i}B_j$$ 
Please, see the following [Melih Sener](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS481/P481-00-proj5.pdf) lecture note by  for a detailed exposition.

Comment: This is not special to three dimensions, right? I.e., the set of classical trajectories of an $n$-dimensional isotropic harmonic oscillator is $CP(n-1)$ and carries an $SU(n)$ action etc?

Comment: Yes, of course, you are correct